# Why doesn't absolute positioning inside relative work?

Tags: html, css-position

I'm a complete beginner at webprogramming so here's my problem:

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/H2V7W/5/) what I have right now. However, as soon as I add `position: absolute` to the two listings the height of the div-element decreases to 1px which is what I do not want.
http://jsfiddle.net/H2V7W/6/

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

ul,
ol {
  border: 1px red solid;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

ul,
ol {
  border: 1px red solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>

  <ol>
    <li>a</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Why is this happening that the two listings seem to have jumped out completely of div?

I thought that I would have "full control" once I do absolute positioning inside relative?

Comment: When you position those elements absolutely, they no longer have any effect on the layout of other elements - you have taken them out of "document flow". You need to apply a height to the `div` explicitly.

Comment: What is the reason for you needing to position your `<ul>` and `<ol>` absolutely?

Comment: This [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) may help you understanding `position` property.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position),

> **absolute**
>       The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties. These properties
>   specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block. **Absolutely
>   positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This means they
>   have no impact on the layout of later siblings.** Also, though
>   absolutely positioned boxes have margins, they do not collapse with
>   any other margins.

Also see this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).